# Batch IF statement comparing variables

Tags: loops, batch-file, numbers, compare

Say I have this batch file:

```
::Stuff

set counter=1
set amount=10

:BEGIN

::More stuff

set /a "counter+=1"
if %counter% LEQ %amount% goto BEGIN
::END
```

It is not continuing even when `counter` reach `amount` . What am I doing wrong?
The reason I am not using a for loop is I need a variable to store the counter, and this would seem to be the easier route, not to mention `FOR` in batch is very weird compared to C-style methods of `for()`.

Solved.
    If command corrected as follows:

```
if /i %counter% LEQ %amount% goto BEGIN
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code works for me. I don't know, whats going on with your batch:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set counter=1
set amount=10

:BEGIN

ECHO %counter%

set /a "counter+=1"
IF %counter% LEQ %amount% goto BEGIN
```

Adding `/i` to `IF` has no impact.